# sorting a comma delineated file with bash

Tags: bash, sorting

I have the following:

```
    http://www.google.com/site,11/30/2012 6:51:30 PM
    http://www.google.com/site,10/1/2012 6:51:30 PM
    http://www.google.com/site,11/16/2012 6:51:30 PM
    http://www.google.com/site,8/1/2012 6:51:30 PM
```

And I want it sorted by MM/DD/YYYY

```
    http://www.google.com/site,8/1/2012 6:51:30 PM
    http://www.google.com/site,10/1/2012 6:51:30 PM
    http://www.google.com/site,11/16/2012 6:51:30 PM
    http://www.google.com/site,11/30/2012 6:51:30 PM
```

I can use sort command, uniq command , tr, sed, etc.  I don't have access to awk. Any ideas ?  `sort -t "," -k1`  sort of worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read line; do
    s=$(date -d "${line#*,}" +%s)
    echo $s $line
done < input.txt | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

So for each line create seconds since Epoch from the date string (which comes after the comma), use that as a sorting key and remove it from the result output.

Comment: is there a way to do this one a single sort command ? I feel like I am close.

Comment: I'm not sure you can tell 'sort' to first check the year, then the month and then the day of month.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
sort -n -t "," -k 2 file.txt
```

See

```
man sort
```

Comment: This won't necessarily work: try with `11/16/2012` and `11/3/2012` as dates for example.

Answer (score 0):

I did some work with the sort command and found out my problem, this seems to be working:

```
    cat s.txt | sort -n -t"/" -k 4,4n -k 5,5n
    https://www.virustotal.com/,9/16/2012 8:19:00 AM
    https://www.virustotal.com/,10/6/2012 9:20:59 AM
    https://www.virustotal.com/,11/1/2012 9:20:22 AM
    https://www.virustotal.com/,11/4/2012 9:11:02 AM
    https://www.virustotal.com/,11/6/2012 8:50:27 AM
    https://www.virustotal.com/,11/12/2012 6:51:32 PM
```

Reversed:

```
    cat s.txt | sort -n -t"/" -k 4,4nr -k 5,5nr
    https://www.virustotal.com/,11/12/2012 6:51:32 PM
    https://www.virustotal.com/,11/6/2012 8:50:27 AM
    https://www.virustotal.com/,11/4/2012 9:11:02 AM
    https://www.virustotal.com/,11/1/2012 9:20:22 AM
    https://www.virustotal.com/,10/6/2012 9:20:59 AM
    https://www.virustotal.com/,9/16/2012 8:19:00 AM
```

However, I need to do this after the  comma because sites with more "/" won't work like `http://site.com/go/to/somelink,9/16/2012 8:19:00 AM`